# Linear and fast mouse speed in OS X Lion. Possible?

Tags: macos, mouse

I've got a 27" display and, at present, I need to use the whole mousepad just to get across the screen.

How can i make my mouse (Logitech MX 400) movement linear AND fast? How do i speed up the mouse with NO acceleration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Preferences > Mouse to speed up or slow down the mouse.

Go to System Preferences > Trackpad to change trackpad speed.

I don't believe acceleration is native to OSX. I have Kensington Trackball Works installed (for my kensington trackball) which has acceleration, and your Logitech Mouse center may have the same. If Logitech Mouse center is System Preferences chances are it will be under "Other".

Comment: Sorry, but I've already have the highest speed already there. Still not fast for me and with dual screens. Any other ideas?

Comment: And i've tried Logitech Mouse, Mouse Curve. No luck there

Comment: You could always try. http://www.logitech.com/en-us/584/3129 (download in right column). The Dpi may be your problem. I have a G7 (no longer made) and it has +/- buttons on it. Slow is SLOW. It's possible the MX 400 has it set too low by default. The software *may* (not sure) allow you to change the dpi.

Comment: Hmm... This is my third MX400 mouse or something.. (got one for my PC and one before). NOW i found out the +/- buttons. Thanks a lot. But i need to tweak it a bit more. :)

Comment: Its shareware, but [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html) is well worth the cost.

Comment: This answer should be deleted, it's not even remotely valid in 2014.

Answer (score 13):

A recently released app called **SmoothMouse** will do exactly what you want, and (in my opinion) works much better than the other alternative mouse drivers.  It's free and available here: http://smoothmouse.com

On top of offering options for both linear and Windows-like acceleration curves, it also removes the 32ms of lag that OSX typically imposes on mouse cursors.  To me, this is just as essential as changing the acceleration.

This thing is really pretty close to the holy grail - great-feeling mouse movement on OSX.

Comment: High Sierra: software can not be used

Comment: SteerMouse still works, and with a little work it can feel very close to SmoothMouse (I use acceleration 0.2 and sensitivity 1905).  Also, recent versions of OSX have significantly improved mouse handling - they no longer have lag, which was part of the issue.

Answer (score 10):

If you want to increase the speed of mouse tracking to fasted then allowed in the system preferences follow these steps:

1. Open Terminal in /Applications/Utilities
2. Type open ~/Library/Preferences/.GlobalPreferences.plist
3. Increase the value of "com.apple.mouse.scaling"
4. Logout/Re-login
5. Repeat until you have set the speed to the desired value

Comment: You could also modify .GlobalPreferences with something like `defaults write -g com.apple.mouse.scaling -float 4.5`. (The default maximum value is 3.0.)

Comment: 8.0 seems good (it's at least seem as fast as the fastest setting on the trackpad). Especially on the Apple 27" Thunderbolt Display.

Comment: I had to restart (not just log out) for it to take effect

Answer (score 2):

Try [MouseZoom](http://benh57.com/mousezoom.html) for all the speed you want! It provides a preferences panel to increase the scaling value beyond the limit imposed by the Mouse panel.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Can you add some detail to this? Where can we download this software? How much does it cost? Why do you like it? Please take a look at the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1st set your system preferences > mouse settings
then get a precision or gaming mouse that has adjustable settings.

I have a 24" imac & use a razer imperator set to maximum sensitivity because I prefer the lack of acceleration with the mouse setting.

in my experience the osx mouse settings do tend to implement acceleration in the tracking speed.

Answer (score 0):

The Speed setting in System Preferences > Mouse should do what you want, I believe.